# Best way to show shapefile in a layered map

Tags: shapefile, google-maps, web-mapping

I'm creating my first app using maps and shapefiles.

I have some shapefiles with attached dbase databases and I would like to show these shapefiles as an overlay on a map.

I have JavaScript code that interprets the SHP and DBF and draws the map, but I don't know how could I put this shapefile on a map.

I thought to use Google Maps or another kind of maps as a base map.

I researched a lot of solutions but I didn't find any solution that really works.

Comment: You mention app: is this a website, or a mobile app? What platform are you working on? Have you considered Leaflet, since you're already working in JavaScript?

Comment: A solution using leaflet would be to convert your shapefile to a geojson file (maybe using Quantum GIS or mapshaper, https://www.npmjs.org/package/mapshaper ), and then displaying this using leaflet. See http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html . Another alternative would be OpenLayers, where this is also possible (see http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/examples/geojson.html ).

Comment: Thanks for both replies. My idea is use for mobile with Titanium. I'm able to create a web solution and use on mobile. I will try the Leaflet solution.

Answer (score 5):

Have you considered using a hosted solution? These days I only roll my own, when one of the cloud based services like ArcGIS Online or Mango don't have what I need out of the box. The spec you are describing is their bread and butter.

Personally I find that [Mango](https://mangomap.com) has the best mobile client. Their pricing is also sharper than ArcGIS Online for smaller projects.